# What is the etymology of "bridge cam gauge"?

Tags: terminology

On the pictures below is a tool called "bridge cam gauge", mentioned [in this answer](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/10352/349). I wonder why the words "bridge" and "cam" are used in its name.

I [found a definition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cam#Noun) of "cam" that might be relevant:

> A curved wedge, movable about an axis, used for forcing or clamping two pieces together.

As I understand, the 'cam' here is the flat roundish beaky plate that you can rotate about its hinge.

But what about "bridge"? [Wiktionary offers a variety of senses](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bridge#Noun), which makes it hard for a non-native speaker of English.

[image]

[image]

[Also asked on ELU SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/333286/48335).

P.S. It is also called "cam type weld gauge"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See here http://www.newmantools.com/gauge/wghowto.htm#wg4 (gauge type WG-4) for how it is used.

It works the same way as a cam. The rotating part (marked "undercut or reinforcement" in your second picture) has a pointed end (marked with the arrow) that "follows" the profile of the parts to be welded like the follower on a conventional cam, as in the graphic in your Wikipedia link.

I think the "bridge" part just means that the gauge has two "feet" that are in contact with the part being measured, and "bridges the gap" between them. See http://marinenotes.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/sketch-and-describe-bridge-gauge-how-is.html for a different type of "bridge gauge", which doesn't have a cam.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of "cam" - it's very clear now! Now the name looks logical.

Comment: Bridge refers to how the gauge is used in the linked picture labeled 'misalignment.' The gauge bridges two separate parts allowing comparison between them.